# php + mysql + utf-8 + спецсимволы

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Приветствую. Есть некий форм который скоро пропадет. Есть необходимость получить его "слепок". Языков он держит много, и там UTF-8.
Работаю с БД в UTF-8, использую и mysql_real_escape_string и mb_convert_encoding так как порой приходят сбойные символы в русскоязычном разделе. И всё бы хорошо (mb_convert_encoding заменяет когда всё совсем печально нечитаемое и не записываемое в БД на "?"), но столкнулся вот с такой красотой "☺️". Она корректно пропускается на заменяясь и не корректируясь и mysql_real_escape_string и mb_convert_encoding но в БД не пишется. Проще говоря строка на этих красотулях обрезается, пишется только то, что до них. Как бы это победить?

P.S. возможно важно указать, что эти символы найдены в рус. части форума, где они идут среди русскоязычных букв UTF-8

Comment: Если обрезает, вероятно всё же там не валидная UTF8-строка..

Comment: Я вот вычитал, что возможно мне нужна utf8mb4 а не utf8 кодировка базы и таблиц. Мол где то порой символы по 4 байта требуют а не по 2.

Comment: А данные корректные храняться в базе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Пересоздал базу в формате utf8mb4_unicode_ci и применил эту же кодировку на все ее таблицы.
Оказалось, что для некоторых спецсимволов в utf8 кодировке, обычного формата базы данных в utf8 не достаточно. Эти символы требуют по 4 байта для записи, а не по 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword dbname --default-charset=utf8 > dump.sql
```